# Why does React rerender Child in this simple example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read a [gazillion](https://overreacted.io/before-you-memo/) [articles](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders) [about](https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide) [renders](https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/) and composition in React, sometimes with contradicting information. At some point I thought I got it, when I read that if React "*still has the same children prop it got from the App last time, React doesn’t visit that subtree.*"

In the code below I am triggering a re-render of `App` every 100ms by setting state, and React outputs "rerendered" in the console every 100ms.

Why does `Child` get re-rendered at each commit? Am I not "lifting content up" here?

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [now, setNow] = useState()

  // Start a timer
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() =>
      setNow(Date.now()), 100)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div id='parent'>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const Child = () => {
  console.log('rendered')
  return (
    <p>whatever</p>
  )
}
```

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const Child = () => {
  console.log('rendered')
  return (
    <p>whatever</p>
  )
}

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div id='parent'>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [now, setNow] = useState()

  // Start a timer
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() =>
      setNow(Date.now()), 100)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are creating a new `<Child />` component everytime the state in the `<App/>` component is updated. So the statement that "if React still has the same children prop it got from the App last time, React doesn’t visit that subtree" is no longer true. If you move your timer from `<App/>` to `<Parent/>` component you can see in the snippet below that the `<Child/>` will no longer rerender because it is only created once in the `<App/>` and passed down as children prop.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const Child = () => {
  console.log('rendered')
  return (
    <p>whatever</p>
  )
}

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const [now, setNow] = useState()

  // Start a timer
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() =>
      setNow(Date.now()), 100)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div id='parent'>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can memoize the `Parent`-`Child` portion inside of `App`. Since the state of `App` is updated every 100ms, it will re-render every 100ms top-down. If you have elements that do not need the `now` value as a prop, you will need to use memoization.

**Note:** I also moved your timer logic into a hook.

```js
const { useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;

const Child = () => {
  console.log('rendered') // only logged one time
  return (
    <p>whatever</p>
  )
}

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const useTime = (updateRateMs) => {
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState()
  const [now, setNow] = useState(Date.now())
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setIntervalId(setInterval(() => setNow(Date.now()), updateRateMs))
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(intervalId)
    }
  }, [intervalId])
  
  return { now }
}

const App = () => {
  const { now } = useTime(100); // Update now every 100ms

  const memoizedChild = useMemo(() => (
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  ), [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {memoizedChild}
      <div>Current Time: {new Date(now).toLocaleString()}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```